# what voltage level is a digital low for the interrupt mode LOW?

Tags: arduino-nano, voltage-level

I am learning about interrupts and one of the interrupt modes is LOW which triggers anytime the pin is a digital low.

Can someone tell me what voltage that is for an Arduino nano? I did a google search and it said a LOW can be anywhere from 0 to 2V.

I am making a project using a nano and I am powering it with batteries. It would be great if I could set up an interrupt to turn on an LED when the batteries were getting weak so I would know when to change them.

Comment: `triggers anytime the pin is a digital low` ... this is bad thinking ... it should be `triggers anytime the pin transitions from high to low` ... there is a vast difference between the two

Answer (score 2):

> It would be great if I could set up an interrupt to turn on an LED
> when the batteries were getting weak

That won't work. The thresholds for the pin registering LOW or HIGH
depend on the supply voltage. Very roughly:

- a pin in guaranteed to register LOW if its voltage is below ⅓ Vcc
- it is guaranteed to register HIGH if it's above ⅔ Vcc
- nothing is guaranteed between ⅓ and ⅔ of Vcc.

For the exact voltage levels, you should check the datasheet.

Note also that those are *guaranteed* levels. The actual thresholds are
closer to ½ Vcc, with an hysteresis of roughly Vcc/10.

For detecting a low battery condition, you should use the ADC, combined
with either a voltage divider on Vcc or the internal bandgap reference.

Comment: Thank you Edgar! I didn't think it would work the way I was wanting it to. That is why I reached out to you folks who are much smarter than I am. I appreciate you answering my question.